# vb.net Getting numbers from array horizontally and vertically?

Tags: vb.net

I have this crazy array.

```
ReDim arrayDeCeldas(filas - 1, columnas - 1)
For i = 0 To filas - 1
    For j = 0 To columnas - 1
        arrayDeCeldas(i, j) = i & j
        Debug.Write(arrayDeCeldas(i, j) & " ")
    Next j
    Debug.WriteLine("")

Next i
```

And I'm trying to link it to a number of conditions and is not well to do
I'm trying to try to get 6 index from array

The number can't repeat and it are pick horizontally or vertically randomly

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
```

This example about i'm try.

It can be seen, there are a total of 6 items with different sizes

[image]
Actually my code, it's getting huge

```
Private Sub setBarco()
        Dim numeroRandom As New System.Random()
        Dim indiceA, indiceB As Integer
        For b = 1 To barcos
            Randomize()
            Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((2 * Rnd() + 1)))
            indiceA = numeroRandom.Next(0, filas)
            indiceB = numeroRandom.Next(0, columnas)
            Select Case b
                Case 1
                    If arrayDeCeldas(indiceA, indiceB) = 0 Then
                        arrayDeCeldas(indiceA, indiceB) = b & 1

                    End If
                Case 2
                    Select Case value
                        Case 1
                            For c = 0 To 1
                                If indiceB + c < columnas Then
                                    If arrayDeCeldas(indiceA, indiceB + c) = 0 Then
                                        arrayDeCeldas(indiceA, indiceB + c) = b & c

                                    End If
                                Else
                                    If arrayDeCeldas(indiceA, indiceB - c) = 0 Then
                                        arrayDeCeldas(indiceA, indiceB - c) = b & c

                                    End If
                                End If
                            Next
                        Case 2

                            For c = 0 To 1
                                If indiceA + c < filas Then
                                    If arrayDeCeldas(indiceA + c, indiceB) = 0 Then
                                        arrayDeCeldas(indiceA + c, indiceB) = b & c

                                    Else

                                    End If
                                Else

                                End If
                            Next
                    End Select
                Case 3
                Case 4
                Case 5
                Case 6
            End Select
        Next b
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are the conditions for selecting numbers? Also, where is your array declared and initialized? Are you using a 2D-array or a staggered-array?

Comment: The selection must be random numbers, but it must meet several conditions, randomly pick horizontally and vertically and that among them is not repeated, as the picture there.
Not to die I'm actually using, but ReDim arrayDeCeldas (rows - 1, columns - 1)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment-reply, I understand the program must:

> Pick at random any six elements from a 2D-array, and each element or value must be selected only once.

That's fairly straightforward: here's a pseudo-code implementation:

1. Perform some initial computation:

   1. Get the bounds of the 2D array
   2. Seed a random number generator:
   3. Create a `HashSet` instance
2. Get six pairs of coordinates:

   1. Loop continuously until `HashSet` has 6 elements in it:

      1. Generate a coordinate pair within the bounds of the array found in Step 1.
      2. Get the value from the coordinate pair
      3. Check to see if we've seen the value before (by looking at the `HashSet`). If we've not seen it before, then add it to the `HashSet` and continue, otherwise ignore it and try again.
3. Return the contents of the `HashSet`

In C# this would be:

```
Int32[,] numbers = new Int32[] { ... };
Int32 maxY = numbers.GetUpperBound(0); // y-axis in dimension 0
Int32 maxX = numbers.GetUpperBound(1); // x-axis in dimension 1
Random rng = new Random();
HashSet<Int32> values = new HashSet<Int32>();
while( values.Count < 6 ) {
    Int32 x = rng.Next( maxX + 1 ); // Random.Next is upperbound exclusive, hence +1
    Int32 y = rng.Next( maxY + 1 );

    Int32 value = numbers[ y, x ];
    if( !values.Contains( value ) ) values.Add( value );
}
return values.ToArray();
```

Note that by keeping track of observed values, instead of coordinates, we can simultaneously avoid duplicate values and duplicate coordinates: as duplicate coordinates will give you duplicate values anyway.

Comment: Actually, this is more complicated to understand than it looks